# Developing search forms with AJAX functionalities

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, search

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.10 and jQuery 1.6. I am planning to develop an HTML form that retrieves some data from the database by performing (multiple) AJAX HTTP requests. I have a couple of questions *about using the above two frameworks in an AJAX "search" scenario*:

1. What do you advice about "data retrieving" with AJAX HTTP requests? Which data type (eg: JSON) it is recommended to use in order to handle a "search" scenario? What other about?
2. When an AJAX search form became an issue (maybe, relating to the number of HTTP AJAX requests)? And how can I handle that\those issue\issues?
3. Are there some good documentation related to implementing AJAX search forms?

Comment: The feature you're looking for is called autocomplete. jQuery UI has this feature built-in: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use this gem to create autocomplete fields for your forms:

https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete

Usage is very simple:

To set up the required action on your controller, all you have to do is call it with the class name and the method as in the following example:

class ProductsController < Admin::BaseController
  autocomplete :brand, :name
end
This will create an action autocomplete_brand_name on your controller, don't forget to add it on your routes file

resources :products do
  get :autocomplete_brand_name, :on => :collection
end